# Show That the Power Spectrum Density Matrix Is Positive Semi Definite (PSD) Matrix

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, time-series, covariance

Given a Wide Sense Stationary **Multi Variate** (Vector) Random Process $ \boldsymbol{x} \left[ n \right] $ its Auto Covariance **Matrix** Function is given by:

$$ {R}_{x, x} \left[ m \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{x} \left[ n \right] \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \left[ n - m \right] \right] $$

Prove that the Power Spectrum Density **Matrix** is [Positive Semi Definite (PSD) Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) where it is given by:

$$ {S}_{x, x} \left( f \right) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} {R}_{x, x} \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi f m} $$

#### Remark

Pay attention that $ {R}_{x, x} \left[ m \right] $ isn't necessarily Positive Semi Definite matrix (It is for $ m = 0 $, yet nothing can be said in general for other time indices). It is even not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: In what way are $R_{x,x}(m)$ and  $S_{x,x}(f)$ considered to be _matrices_? It looks like they are _sequences_ of numbers: OK, at best matrices in which one dimension is 1 but how is positive definiteness defined in this case?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, If we're dealing with a Process of Random Vector those are matrices. Not $ 1 \times 1 $ but actual matrices. For example if $ \boldsymbol{x} \left[ n \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{k} $ then $ {R}_{x, x} \left[ m \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k} \; \forall m $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention that for a Scalar Random Process the Power Spectrum Density is non negative.

Namely, let $ y \left[ n \right] \in \mathbb{R} $ be a WSS Random process with its Auto Correlation function given by:

$$ {R}_{y, y} \left[ m \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ y \left[ n \right] y \left[ n - m \right] \right] $$

Then the Power Spectrum Density is:

$$ {S}_{y, y} \left( f \right) = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} {R}_{y, y} \left[ m \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi f m} \geq 0 $$

Then, by defining $ z \left[ n \right] = \boldsymbol{v}^{T} \boldsymbol{x} \left[ n \right] $ one would get:

$$ \begin{align*}
0 \leq {S}_{z, z} \left( f \right) & =  \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} \left[ z \left[ n \right] {z}^{T} \left[ n - m \right] \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi f m} \\
& = \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{v}^{T} \boldsymbol{x} \left[ n \right] \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \left[ m - m \right] \boldsymbol{v} \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi f m} \\
& = \boldsymbol{v}^{T} \left( \sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} \left[ \boldsymbol{x} \left[ n \right] \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \left[ n - m \right] \right] {e}^{-j 2 \pi f m} \right) \boldsymbol{v} \\
& = \boldsymbol{v}^{T} {S}_{x, x} \left( f \right) \boldsymbol{v} \\
& \Rightarrow {S}_{x, x} \left( f \right) \succeq 0
\end{align*} $$

Some remarks regarding simulating it in MATLAB:

- If one use MATLAB's `xcorr()` to calculate the Auto Correlation one should use `ifftshift()` to shift the function to be "Symmetric" to MATLAB in order to have the DFT Real and Non Negative. This is due to the fast MATLAB's `fft()` expects the first sample to be of index $ 0 $ (See the `lags` output of `xcorr()`).

Comment: Why is this true in the scalar case?

Comment: @Exodd, what do you mean?

Comment: why is the PSD nonnegative in the scalar case, if you define it starting from the autocorrelation?

Comment: Because the cross correlation basically equals to the DFT of the signal multiplied by its conjugate. So it is norm, non negative.